# We miss TheTXI!

Tags: discussion, support, fun

I can't help but wonder what has happen to TheTXI lately.  Has he been put on demanding project that has taken all his free time?  He hasn't responded to anything on meta since Nov 6, on SU Oct 9, SO Nov 4, etc.  We miss his sly helpful answers on meta and his blunt to the point SU responses, and those ever so useful SO posts. Has Diago done such an awesome job that he doesn't need to do much to SU lately? The dude has gone into silence and used to comment/answer all the time. He has so much rep, he didn't even move spots in the top users of meta. When will TheTXI return?

http://ponyoverflow.com

EDIT: Whoever has his email or contact with him should send him a link to this question. Does he respond to his contact info in his meta profile?

EDIT 2:  Please see Jeff Atwood's answer for further information.  And congrats to Ivo becoming part of the moderator team!

Comment: What if he's dead?

Comment: He was abducted by aliens disguised as ponies... who could resist?

Comment: @random NOOOOO!!!!!

Comment: What's this "We" business?

Comment: @random: Don't talk like that. If you say it enough on the Internet, it will become true. I know its true, I read it on the Internet.

Comment: I have mailed him and he has been receiving moderator e-mails, no responses thought. It is strange since he often replies from his iPhone. I know he doesn't have access to meta or superuser at work however.

Comment: @Diago: iPhone is the reason I can respond to so much email and sites like this without being near a computer many days. Sounds like work has got the best of him lately.

Comment: When is the "Where has Rich B?" question coming?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question...

Comment: Could this be him? http://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies

Comment: @DanThMan: No, that's the user formerly known as rexem.

Comment: Really? A 1 year old typo? By the way, where are you TXI?

Comment: I was hoping this was bumped because there was news. You have made me sad, @RegDwight.

Comment: @mmyers: Sorry! Then again, TheTXI does need a reminder that we *still* miss him!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know, he hasn't even responded to recent moderator-related emails, either.

Nothing urgent, mind you, but the lack of response was odd.. guess he's busy!

Now this is getting serious. I can't get any response to emails on multiple email addresses, and these are his "last-seen" dates:

SO: Nov 30
SF: Sep 8
**SU: Oct 28**
ME: Dec 7

This is a bit of a problem, since TheTXI is a moderator on Super User and he hasn't been seen once there in two full months.

Ah, finally got a response. Seems work is in permanent lockdown mode, and there's lots of "stuff" going on at home. Glad he's OK at least! He agrees that we should transfer his mod to someone else who has more time to work with it.

We need someone who is actively participating on SU on a daily basis. [Ivo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130099/ivo) was one of the runner ups in the SU moderator election, and he is an active participant to this day on SU. **Effective immediately, I am transferring TheTXI's moderator status to [Ivo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130099/ivo).**

Comment: You drove him away! How could you have more rep than him on meta? You have no heart! The poor pony...

Comment: So far, it sounds like work has got the best of TheTXI lately.

Comment: @Troggy Nonsense! Jeff's probably turned him into glue by now. Either that or Rich B had something to do with it; he's also conspicuously missing.

Comment: I'm just really glad to hear that he is still around. I must admit, I had concerns for his well-being. Very relieved, thanks for the update.

Comment: I'm wondering why transfer?  Why not just add Ivo?  I don't see any cost in adding another moderator, and TheTXI is unlikely to lose that much touch that he would be bad at it when he's ready to come back.

Comment: I agree. Ivo is a good choice to add to the mod team at SU.  He was another great nomination in the most recent SU moderator poll.

Answer (score 22):

He's in IRC. Let me see if he's at his keyboard. <sup><sub>Just upvote me a lot in anticipation.</sub></sup>

The logs say the last thing he said was today, at 17:16 ADT:

> `<TheTXI>` "the general ledger of this application needs to work perfectly by January 1st, so I'll probably need you to put in extra hours this month"
>   `<TheTXI>` whenever my boss does this I get the sudden urge to start looking for other jobs

Before that, at 17:03 ADT:

> `<TheTXI>` I love when a boss goes and makes unrealistic promises or expectations and then expects you to work like a dog to try and fulfill those unrealistic expectations
>   `<TheTXI>` and then you don't get rewarded when you inevitably fail to live up to unrealistic unexpectations

This answer is like that movie Memento. Remember that? The main character sure doesn't! *[rimshot]* 16:15 ADT:

> `<TheTXI>` yes

This is in reply to Mike Hudson saying:

> `<whodey>` ever bid on something and then look closer and really start to hope you'll get outbid?

Most of his earlier stuff around noon ADT is like this:

> `<TheTXI>` wtf
>   `<TheTXI>` whodey: only if you were equipment manager
>   `<TheTXI>` rofl
>   `<TheTXI>` you would
>   `<TheTXI>` there's two z's?
>   `<TheTXI>` it was either evansville or drake that Hansbrough broke the unc scoring record against

It's things like this that make me really hate that guy.

He's not replying to my hailing signals from a few minutes ago (Inferno is me):

> `<Inferno>` Hey, the TXI
>   `<Inferno>` Where you at?
>   `<Inferno>` I take it you're not here.
>   `<Inferno>` The guys are looking for you: [We miss TheTXI!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31752/txi-sucks)

Notice that I use punctuation. TXI never does that. I hate that guy.

This is #somafia on irc.slashnet.org, by the way. It's where cool people like Welbog idle. Today is the first time I've sent something to that channel in like two weeks. Though usually when I do type stuff it's along the lines of "Jeff Atwood sure is silly" but with better vocabularity. "Vocabularity" is a portmanteau of the words "vocabulary" and "vulgarity".

Exciting update (21:13 ADT):

> --> zaatkin (~zaatkin@cloak-E6292A23.san.res.rr.com) has joined #somafia
>   `<zaatkin>` why has TheTXI disappeared?
>   `<zaatkin>` NO!!!!!!!!
>   `<Inferno>` Shinjae
>   <-- zaatkin has quit (Quit: zaatkin)
>   --> zaatkin (~zaatkin@cloak-E6292A23.san.res.rr.com) has joined #somafia
>   `<zaatkin>` huh?
>   `<Inferno>` Shinjae
>   <-- zaatkin has quit (Quit: zaatkin)

I don't know who that guy was, but I sure showed him! I continue to lie in wait for TXI sightings at least for an hour or so before I go to sleep.

Still nothing. No TXI sightings in sight. I swore a bunch in IRC, though. That's activity. I'm not going to paste it here. If you want to see my vocabularity you can just log into Wave or IRC your lazy self.

**What is happening?!**

> --> TehTXI (Mibbit@cloak-1C1D00B7.americas.lc.americanstandard.com) has joined #somafia
>   `<Inferno>` OH NO
>   `<YummyBot>` oh no are we about to jump into the rotary engine debate again
>   `<Inferno>` A DOPPELGANGER
>   `<Inferno>` I WILL EAT YOUR FACE OFF AND REVEAL THE TRUTH
>   `<TehTXI>` My face is tasty. Like waffles and pizza and chocolate mousse
>   `<Inferno>` You're not TXI. TXI doesn't use punctuation.
>   `<TehTXI>` thats truth yes its isnt obvious
>   `<Inferno>` I'm convinced.
>   `<Inferno>` Where have you been? Everyone is looking for you.
>   `<TehTXI>` eating ponies and pizzas and stuff
>   `<TehTXI>` i gain a powerful hunger come winter
>   `<Inferno>` I'm getting skeptical again. TXI does not eat ponies. That's *[expletive deleted]* cannibalism.
>   `<Inferno>` But he is fat, so you have that going for you.
>   --> DaTXI (Mibbit@cloak-1C39BE42.clsp.qwest.net) has joined #somafia
>   `<Inferno>` *[expletive deleted]*
>   `<DaTXI>` *[expletive deleted]* doesnt *[expletive deleted]*
>   `<DaTXI>` *[expletive deleted]*  is where *[expletive deleted]* go for *[expletive deleted]*  too much
>   `<Inferno>` *[expletive deleted]* right.

The replicon TXIs have vacated the channel. Still no sign of the real deal, so I'm going to call it a night. See you *[expletive delete]* later.

Comment: Maybe he should be on careers then

Comment: What, have you been wasting time on Wave instead?

Comment: @random: Yeah. Wave is way more fun than IRC. For example, it doesn't have TXI on it.

Comment: Fun if you can actually load a wave. Plus at least you can give people another avatar if you so wish.

Comment: And I can change my avatar and it'll *actually change*, unlike here on static-avatars-overflow.

Comment: @random: that's part of the fun!

Comment: You can get a quick updated avatar change if you swap out your email address. No problem. Problem is keeping it all in check though.

Comment: It's a shame doppelgängers don't do any research any more.

Comment: It'll all end in tears if this transcript causes him to lose his job. :(

Comment: hey, i know that zaatkin guy...

Comment: +1 for using "portmanteau" properly in a sentence, and for "Vocabularity." Oh, and for tracking down the pony-god, too.

Comment: No really, I do know that zaatkin person. Seriously!

Comment: @Æther - Actually it would achieve the goal of this question quite neatly.

Comment: What does "shinjae" mean?

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Comment: He canters still ;-p

Comment: He's watching us...

Answer (score 7):

Has he been put out to pasture? He couldn't have gone to glue as he would still stick around...

Comment: His name would change to ThePaste though.

Comment: What about TheGLU?

Comment: You are in a cavern full of twisty passages.  You are likely to be eaten by TheGlu.